What force does a braking caravan exercise?
I'm not a physicist, and I hope this isn't a naive question!
Let's assume a car towing a caravan has powerful anti-lock brakes. Let's also assume the caravan has a braking system, as required in law, but it's less powerful than that of the car.
In the event of an emergency stop, does the caravan on its own exercise a stopping force or a forward force on the car + caravan vehicle?

Exactly what do you mean by “less powerful”?

The caravan (trailer) is most likely lighter than the car, and its brakes should handle the trailer just fine. There are many trailers without brakes, and they can be towed just fine.

Let's assume the car has mass $m_1$ and its brakes exert a maximum force $F_1$, and the caravan has mass $m_2$ and its brakes exert a maximum force $F_2$.
The car and caravan together has mass $m_1+m_2$ and their brakes together exert a maximum force $F_1+F_2$, which will lead to a joint deceleration of the car and caravan of
$\displaystyle d = \frac {F_1+F_2} {m_1+m_2}$
The net force on the caravan must therefore be
$\displaystyle m_2d = \frac {m_2(F_1+F_2)} {m_1+m_2}$
Suppose there is a tension $T$ in the tow bar  between the car and the caravan. Then we have
$F_2 - T = m_2d
\\ \Rightarrow T = F_2 - m_2d$
As long as $T\ge 0$ then everything is fine - both car and caravan are braking and the tow bar is in tension so the braking caravan is "holding back" the car. However, if $T < 0$ then the tow bar is in compression and the caravan is "pushing" the car. The condition $T\ge 0$ is equivalent to
$F_2 \ge m_2d
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow F_2 \ge \frac {m_2(F_1+F_2)} {m_1+m_2}
\\ \Rightarrow F_2(m_1+m_2) \ge m_2(F_1+F_2)
\\ \Rightarrow m_1 F_2 \ge m_2 F_1$

It depends on how hard you're braking. I will take "more/less powerful" brakes to mean that the car brake can cause a greater deceleration of the car than the trailer brake can for the trailer.
If you brake lightly and keep the deceleration below what the trailer's brakes can provide, then no force is transferred to the car - the trailer would be able stop even if it weren't hitched to the car. If you brake harder than that, then the car would slow faster than the trailer, but it doesn't because of the hitch - some of the car's braking force slows the trailer in this case.
If the trailer had no brakes whatsoever, then obviously the car's brakes would be the only thing stopping it. If on the other hand the car had no brakes and the trailer did, the trailer brakes would be the only thing stopping the car. In general, it's possible for the car brakes to slow the trailer, or for the trailer brakes to slow the car, or for neither to happen - depending on exactly what is meant by the statement that the trailer brakes are "less powerful" than the car's, and depending on how hard you're braking, it seems likely that either the car brakes apply a force to slow the trailer, or have no effect at all if it's not a hard stop.

If I rephrase this a little, I'd like to remove "... on its own..." from the question sentence, and I'm going to rephrase "stopping force" as "backwards force."  Thus the question is what direction is the force of the caravan on the car. I phrase it that way because that phrasing will be closer to what we use when trying to describe such physics, making it a bit easier to see how the variables are going to work out.
The last big question is how to define "less powerful brakes."  It turns out that it doesn't matter how you define it, for the answer to your question will be "it depends."  However, one way of defining it yields more physical insight than the others.  Let $F_{brake\to car}$ be the force that the car's wheels apply to the car (due to the car's brakes), and let $F_{brake\to caravan}$ be the force that the caravan's wheels apply to the caravan (due to its brakes).  Also, let's state that forward is the positive direction.  That's the most traditional direction, and generates the least confusion.  This means both braking forces are negative (going in the backwards direction).  Finally, let's define some variable $k$ such that $F_{brake\to car} = kF_{brake\to caravan}$.  In other words, $k$ is a number greater than 1 indicating how much more powerful the car brakes are.  Again, there are different ways to think about it.  You could also use addition rather than multiplication, but multiplication will turn out to yield better insights when wer'e done.
Now if you draw some freebody diagrams, you will see that the car and caravan each have two forces applied to it.  The caravan has $F_{brake\to caravan}$ and $F_{car\to caravan}$, the latter being the force applied by the car to the caravan.  The car has $F_{brake\to car}$ and $F_{caravan\to car}$, the latter being the force applied by the caravan to the car (which is the quantity you are asking about in the question).  Due to Newton's third law, we know that the force on the car by the caravan and the force on the caravan by the car are equal and opposite, so we can write $F_{car\to caravan}$ = -$F_{caravan\to car}$
To bring this all together, we can write the equations of motion for both vehicles.  We will use $F=ma$ for both:
$$F_{brake\to car} + F_{caravan\to car} = m_{car}a_{car}$$
$$F_{brake\to caravan} + F_{car\to caravan} = m_{caravan}a_{caravan}$$
Now I'm going to do three substitutions.  The first is to recognize that because the vehicles are physically coupled together, $a_{car} = a_{caravan}$.  If this was not true, the caravan would be accelerating away from the car, which we call a runaway caravan and we really hope that it still has chains holding it in place and making sure it doesn't veer into oncomming traffic!  So I'm just going to replace both with a single variable, $a$. The second substitution is to use $F_{car\to caravan}$ = -$F_{caravan\to car}$ to replace  $F_{car\to caravan}$.  You could also use it to replace $F_{caravan\to car}$, and reason about it the same way, but since the wording of your question specifically asks about the caravan to car force, we'll use this one.  Finally, we will replace $F_{brake\to car}$ with $kF_{brake\to caravan}$ from the earlier equation.  When we do all of these, we get:
$$kF_{brake\to caravan} + F_{caravan\to car} = m_{car}a$$
$$F_{brake\to caravan} - F_{caravan\to car} = m_{caravan}a$$
We can then divide both sides by their corresponding mass, leaving $a$ on the right hand side of both equations
$$\frac{kF_{brake\to caravan} + F_{caravan\to car}}{m_{car}} = a$$
$$\frac{F_{brake\to caravan} - F_{caravan\to car}}{m_{caravan}} = a$$
Since the right hand sides are equal, we can set the left hand side to be equal.
$$\frac{kF_{brake\to caravan} + F_{caravan\to car}}{m_{car}} = \frac{F_{brake\to caravan} - F_{caravan\to car}}{m_{caravan}}$$
Now its time to try to reorganize this equation to get $F_{caravan\to car}$, which is the variable you were looking for in the first place: the force of the caravan on the car. No physics here, just a bit of algebra.
$$m_{caravan}kF_{brake\to caravan} + m_{caravan}F_{caravan\to car} = m_{car}F_{brake\to caravan} - m_{car}F_{caravan\to car}$$
$$m_{caravan}F_{caravan\to car} + m_{car}F_{caravan\to car}= m_{car}F_{brake\to caravan} - - m_{caravan}kF_{brake\to caravan}$$
$$(m_{caravan} + m_{car})F_{caravan\to car} = (m_{car}-km_{caravan})F_{brake\to caravan}$$
$$F_{caravan\to car} = \frac{m_{car}-km_{caravan}}{m_{caravan} + m_{car}}F_{brake\to caravan}$$
Now we can see that the force of the caravan to the car is proportional to the force of the brake on the caravan, which makes sense.  For purposes of your question, though, the interesting question is which direction does it go in.  That depends on the sign of $\frac{m_{car}-km_{caravan}}{m_{caravan} + m_{car}}$.  If that's positive, the caravan applies a backwards force (you called it "stopping"), because that force will be in the same direction as the braking force.  If that value is negative, the caravan will apply a positive force (you called it "forward"), so le'ts look at it in detail.  In particular, lets look at when it is greater than zero:
$$\frac{m_{car}-km_{caravan}}{m_{caravan} + m_{car}}\ge 0$$
Assuming the the car+caravan combo is not massless (a safe assumption!), the denominator is greater than 0, so we can safely multiply by $m_{caravan} + m_{car}$ on both sides.  The right side, is of course, 0, as anything times 0 is 0:
$$m_{car}-km_{caravan}\ge 0$$
$$m_{car}\ge km_{caravan}$$
Now we have your answer.  That constant is positive (meaning the caravan has a "stopping: force on the car) if $m_{car}\ge km_{caravan}$.  If instead $m_{car}\lt km_{caravan}$, it will have a forward force.  And, obviously if $m_{car}= km_{caravan}$ it will apply no force at all -- the brakes are perfectly balanced.
And so, the answer after much algebra is: it depends.  Its a matter of proprtionality between how much weaker the brakes are on the caravan and how much less massive the caravan is.
